# Modal strange behavior Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

When I present a modal in ionic 2, it comes with a slight gray overlay and when i try to interact with content, any click or touch dismisses it.

I tried with option showBackdrop set to false, which prevents the modal from dismissing but I still can't interact with it's content :

[I can't interact with the form right here :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J8Ei.png)

I present the modal with this function :

```
presentDetail(){
    let opts = {
        showBackdrop: false,
        enableBackdropDismiss: false,
    };

    let beaconModal = this.modalCtrl.create(DetailBeacon, opts);

    beaconModal.present();
}
```

This occurs in browser and android 4.4

```
My system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

I looked for the issue and looks like I'm the only one..

I could use some help

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/#create) create method is having 3 parameter, only in the third parameter we should be able to send the options for Modal but you sent the options in 2nd parameter.